# Book about alien ships emerging from holes in the earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, alien-invasion

There's a book I read that I've forgotten the name of. It was sci-fi about archaeologists at a dig site finding alien artifacts. At some point giant ships emerge from holes in the earth and wipe out most of humanity. The aliens had been on earth for centuries molding humanity how they see fit. I'm sure one of them acted like a Roman or was from the Roman era.

The remaining humans are farmed by the aliens, I think for meat, but a few humans hide and live in the forest. When the aliens start to terraform the planet the new plants grown allow a human male and his son to grow super strong to fight alien troops and ambush the human farms and the giant machines terraforming the planet.

Later he meets engineers who build him a device to take down one of the ships (I think). He somehow gets off the earth and goes to another planet to fight for the aliens who invaded earth because there is a worse race fighting them.

The author had two initials then a name e.g. 'E.L. James' or something like that. It was a trilogy of books; I just can't find the name again.

Comment: The aliens start to terraform the planet ***Earth???*** What does that mean? They are trying to make the Earth even more Earthlike???

Comment: @user14111 More their own home planet, I would presume.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish But that wouldn't be **terra**forming.

Comment: @user14111 Oh, I don't know, they might  just want to take their home planet (Earth) back to the reducing atmosphere it had 3 billion years ago.

Comment: What term would you suggest @user14111

Comment: @ConradBennishJr I don't know a word for that. I guess I would resort to using several words. Something like "modifying the Earth's environment to be more suitable to their form of life."

Comment: @user14111 or maybe a term everyone’s familiar with and even if it doesn’t pedantically fit, sums up the general idea? Like ‘terraform’?

Comment: "Xenoforming" is a commonly-used term, though I feel like OP's question was clear enough as it was. There's no need to split hairs.

Comment: @ConradBennishJr Using a term that "doesn't pedantically fit" is one thing; using a word that means exactly the opposite of what you're trying to say is another thing.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 thank you for politely providing a useful suggestion.